# Slow writing speed to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, samba, network-share

I have a problem with **slow writing speed via mapped network drive** (samba) on Windows Server 2012R2.

I'll describe my network and tests below:

I have two computers both running W8.1 (Desktop and Notebook) with one 1gb/s NIC,
then ESXi 6 Update 2 running two VM's (WS 2012 and debian).
Both VM's are located on SSD in the same storage, both have one Virtual NIC - VMXNET3 (same Port group (two physical 1gb/s NICs in one vSwitch)).
WS2012 is not in AD.

**Folders to share:**
W8.1 Desktop - "share"
WS 2012 - "sharing"
debian - "test"

I did a few test by copying a single file (~700MB), everytime with different file, so it wouldn't be somehow compromised tests:)

**Here are the results, speeds of transfer were very constant:**

Windows 8.1 Desktop (uploading) > WS 2012 = **~33MB/s** (downloading)
Windows 8.1 notebook (uploading) > WS 2012 = **~33MB/s** (downloading)
debian (uploading) > WS 2012 (downloading) = **123MB/s** (I mapped folder "test" in windows and downloaded the file)

Windows 8.1 Desktop (uploading) > debian = 113MB/s (downloading)
Windows 8.1 Desktop (uploading) > Windows 8.1 notebook = 113MB/s (downloading)
Windows 8.1 notebook (uploading) > Windows 8.1 desktop = 113MB/s (downloading)

WS 2012 (uploading) > debian = 120MB/s (downloading)
WS 2012 (uploading) > Windows 8.1 Desktop = 111MB/s (downloading)

---

I will be glad, if anybody helps:)
I've found many similar guestions, but I did not find the solution:(

Thanks

Leo

Comment: What is the total/available memory of the 2012 R2 server?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your question, I had 2GB, I increased to 4GB, and nothing changed. In the Task Manager it shows 1,3GB all the time. Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found the problem:)
in Vipre Firewall - Intrusion Detection Systems(IDS), if it's on then is it really slow connection, after shutting it down, speed increased to 100+MB/s.

Leo